# Converting Boostrap Template To Drupal thememe

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, drupal, drupal-7, converters, drupal-8

I wanted to know how to convert my bootstrap template into drupal theme while taking into account my JQuery code in my bootstrap template. Help me please I block for weeks on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition, you might want to install Bootstrap3 based Drupal theme : https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap

and then create a subtheme based on Bootstrap base theme : 
https://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/docs%21subtheme%21README.md/group/subtheme/7

Enjoy coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't just "convert" template to Drupal theme. You should build new Drupal theme and re-use some parts of your existing template. Find some neat tutorial and learn how to make drupal Theme. There is no magic convertor for this. You have to do it on your own.

https://valuebound.com/resources/blog/a-step-step-guide-to-drupal-7-custom-theme-development

http://www.tenten71.com/drupal-theme-from-scratch/

https://blog.templatetoaster.com/create-drupal-theme-from-scratch/

Comment: Thanks so much, there no magic convertor for this but these links are magics